# Cannot Connect from Hyper-V Manager on Windows 10 to Hyper-V Server 2012 R2

Tags: hyper-v

Just as the title says, I'm having a bit of a problem connecting from a Hyper-V Manager instance on a Windows 10 machine to a Hyper-V Server 2012 which is found on the same network. Neither of them, however, is joined to AD/DNS/etc... they are both running in WORKGROUP and I'm trying to access the server with the \server\user path and with a user on the server with admin rights and privileges to all of the connected services.

I keep getting the following:

> "An error occurred while attempting to connect to server. Check that
>   the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are
>   authorized to connect to the server." "You do not have the required
>   permission to complete this task. Contact the administrator of the
>   authorization policy for the computer."

I have pretty much depleted all of Google's natural resources on this topic and this particular error and I can confirm that nothing from different workarounds/tutorials worked and that all of the relevant services are in fact started/working etc.

Any ideas please? :)

Comment: Have a look into this Microsoft forum https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7b4d00c-7808-4666-bd81-32e78fdb4087/using-windows-10-hyperv-manager-to-manage-hyperv-server-2012r2-hosts?forum=winserverhyperv

Answer (score 3):

If you are not signed in as administrator, when you open hyper-v manager "run as administrator"

Answer (score 2):

Add the target account credentials to the Windows Credential Manager from the command line and try reconnecting
cmdkey /add:TARGET /user:TARGET\USER /pass

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you run the PowerShell terminal as administrator ("run as administrator")